# Any difference between while(true) and for(;;)?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I know both of these create intentional infinite loops, and I have a friend who bugs me to no end about using `for(;;)` as opposed to `while(true)`. Is there any difference between the two besides `while(true)` being more commonly accepted as the "correct" syntax, i.e. memory usage or cycle speed?

Comment: Ideally both are same as infinite loop.

Comment: Look at the Related column over on the right -->

Comment: If Iwere a compiler, I would generate the exact same assembly for both.

Comment: I **am** a compiler, and I **do** generate the exact same assembly for both.

Comment: does anyone noticed that this question specifies no language ? How you can offer even an opinion starting from such a question.

Comment: @user2485710 It's tagged as C

Comment: @CandyMan it was edited, the question still doesn't specifies anything . The original question was not tagged `C` or any other language.

Answer (score 3):

They are exactly the same:
Inspecting the generated assembly file (using -S) by GCC, one can see that the compiler generates identical instructions for both.

`for` loop:

```
.L2:
    jmp .L2
```

`while` loop:

```
.L4:
    jmp .L4
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no functional difference between the two statements.  `while(true)` might be a little clearer for a new user to understand, whereas `for(;;)` is a bit more cryptic.  The compiler, however, reads them as basically the same.

The effect of them is to create an infinite loop.